# What is the sound you often make when you are annoyed called?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, vocabulary

As in: "ugh(?)", is it him again?

Answer (score 2):

*[Ugh](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/ugh)* can be used in your example. It is the sound that people make when something is extremely unpleasant (Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English).

Answer (score 1):

The sound itself is called a *harrumph*. You could also call it a *grunt* or a *sigh* depending on the exact connotation you're looking for.

If you are looking for an onomatopoeia, "ugh" is probably the most common spelling. Others include "ack" "blech".